# Como chamar outra ação e retornar o valor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Segue código:

```
public ActionResult Teste1(int num1, int num2)
{
   var valor = Teste2(1, 2); //Aqui recebe valor nulo
}

public ActionResult Teste2(int num11, int num22)
{
   //Alguns valores aqui...
   var valor = 123;
   return null;
}
```

Os valores que estão na ação `Teste2`, passar para ação `Teste1` com variável `valor`, isso é possível ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Os valores que estão na ação Teste2, passar para ação Teste1 com variável valor, isso é possível?

Possível, é, mas isso é uma má prática.

Repare que o retorno de `Teste1` e de `Teste2` é um `ActionResult`, ou seja, um resultado completo de uma ação executada em *Controller*. Portanto, só não seria má prática se a ideia fosse algo como:

```
public ActionResult Teste1(int num1, int num2)
{
   return Teste2(1, 2); // veja este retorno.
}

public ActionResult Teste2(int num11, int num22)
{
   //Alguns valores aqui...
   var valor = 123;
   return Content(valor); // veja aqui também.
}
```

Se a ideia é reaproveitamento de lógica, declare *Helpers* (classes estáticas com métodos estáticos dentro), que são mais eficientes e o retorno é em variáveis que você define.

Comment: Essa é a forma mais correta ou existe outra maneira ?

Comment: A demonstrada no exempo da resposta é a mais correta, inclusive, no tocante à herança, que também pode ser usada dessa forma.